# Eclipse boost_system (arm-linux) linking error

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, arm, gumstix

I have repeatedly tried to include the boost_thread library in my eclipse project, but every time I compile the code I get this error:

/home/user/gumstix/gumstix-oe/tmp/cross/lib/gcc/arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/4.1.2/../../../../arm-angstrom-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld:cannot find -lboost_system
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I have included the library in the GCC C++ Linker Libraries section under Project properties, Also, this code is using arm-linux-g++ to compile as I am porting the code over to a gumstix. I am using Ubuntu.

I have looked high and low for the answer to my problem, but to no avail.

Comment: Did you see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794625/boost-linkage-error-in-eclipse?rq=1 ?

Comment: Ya I looked at that already. My files are libboost_thread.a and libboost_thread.so, so it does't change anything unfortunately