# Cannot find -libboost_system

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I am running across a problem similar to [Boost linkage error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794625/boost-linkage-error-in-eclipse). I have a program which includes boost/filesystem.hpp.

When I try to compile my program with eclipse I get the following error.

```
g++ -libboost_system -o "crcTools2"  ./crcThing.o   -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system-mt
/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.7.2/ld: cannot find -libboost_system
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see, I am compiling using g++ 4.7.2 from devtoolset-1.1 and am running CentOs. The boost version is 1.57.
I have tried with both `boost_system` and `boost_system-mt` as my libraries. When I run

```
ldconfig -v | grep -i "libboost_system"
```

I get

```
libboost_system-mt.so.5 -> libboost_system-mt.so.5
libboost_system.so.5 -> libboost_system.so.5
```

I'm sure there's something wrong with my configuration but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's complaining about `-libboost_system` you put at the beginning. This is incorrect linker option.

Comment: Totally forgot I did that when I was trying to figure out how to link the libraries. Thanks!